# How to change multiple values in a json using jq by selecting them by key and getting whole json output

Tags: json, shell, jq

I have following data.json to be modified , I want to change the state to "disabled" based on the filtered IP address range(eg "10.13*". I tried following command and I need to get whole json content as the out put, but i'm getting a syntax errors for this(I have used same for updating a single value(without using character mapping), it worked fine. (Plan is to use this in shell command and redirect the out put to a new file). Can someone help me on this

```
jq '(.[]| select(.node|test("^10.13*"))).state |="disabled" data.json
```

```
[
    {
        "node":"10.13.248.254:61052",
        "state": "active"
    },
    {
        "node":"10.13.248.255:61052",
        "state": "active"
    },
    {
        "node":"10.54.247.228:61052",
        "state": "active"
    },
    {
        "node":"10.54.247.229:61052",
        "state": "active"
    }
]
```

Comment: Fix your input JSON. The quotes are misplaced. The jq filter seems fine - https://jqplay.org/s/AbKf9UMR31l

Comment: Thanks , I have corrected my data.json file, and I can see correct values in the jqplay, but when I execute it in the shell , jq '<command>' data.json I'm getting the following erro ``` jq: error (at data.json:22): Invalid path expression near attempt to access  element "state" of {"node":"10.13.248.254:610....

Comment: Your filter [works](https://jqplay.org/s/eDKPPBnph2V) but your command-line lacks the closing single quote (`... = "disabled" ' data.json`). Also, using the update operator `|=` is superfluous here, just use the assignment operator `=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex isn’t quite right. Also, it might be worthwhile using `map` to make things more straightforward:

```
map(if (.node|test("^10[.]13[.]")) then .state="disabled" else . end)
```

Or you could simply use `startswith`.

---

In response to the follow-up question:

If your array lives at `_` in `{"properties": { "basic": {"nodes_table": _}}}`, you'd write:

```
.properties.basic.nodes_table |= map(....)
```

Comment: Thanks for this,  this really works, i tried this command when there are parent objects like "properties { basic { nodes_table [ node : 10.13.248...in the json, tried several ways using above code , but nothing gives me full out put with changed content, do you kniw where should Inplace parent objects filters in order to get full out put?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to modify array elements whose IP address starts with "10.13.", you'd usually use `map` and combine with `startswith` (for prefix-matching the IP address):

```
jq 'map(select(.node|startswith("10.13.")).state = "disabled")' input.json
```

An equivalent solution assigning multiple values at once:

```
jq '(.[]|select(.node|startswith("10.13")).state) = "disabled"' input.json
```

Note that the second solution is almost identical to your proposed one (with slight modifications: different grouping, `startswith`, and the plain assignment operator)